# Use yml file instead of persistence.xml for configuring jpa

Tags: jpa

I am trying to write a simple jpa application htat performs CRUD operations on a table.Currently I am using persistence.xml to configure the connection.
I want to use a yml file to do the configuration.How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The JPA spec is very clear about requiring a file `persistence.xml`.

Comment: I've seen people using application.yml. Can I do that or is it for a different purpose?

Comment: The JPA API does NOT process any `application.yml`. Suggest that you talk to those other people and ask what OTHER software they are using to process it